# IAudioClient cutting short sounds

Tags: c++, windows, audio, audio-streaming

I try to play a WAV file using `IAudioClient` but I get really strange behavior. If I try to play very short sounds (approx. 0.2s - 0.3s) they get cutting off in the end or in the beginning. The exact behavior can be observer in Windows Media Player. However, if some other app is playing sound (Google Chrome tab, Spotify, audio file is opened in VS Code editor) then my program plays sounds correctly (as well as Windows Media Player).

Here's a complete sample code that demonstrates the problem (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/rendering-a-stream). Can someone provide a hypothesis or an exact problem in my approach? The source code is long but it's complete and everything inside `AudioSource` class should be working correct, it's just file reading and resampling logic. I guess the problem is somewhere in the algorithm of function `Run`.

```
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mftransform.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <wmcodecdsp.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>

#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")

using namespace std;

#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres) \
    if (FAILED(hres)) { return hres; }

constexpr REFERENCE_TIME ReftimesPerSecond = 10'000'000;
constexpr REFERENCE_TIME ReftimesPerMillisecond = 10'000;

struct WaveHeader
{
    CHAR riff[4];
    UINT32 fileSize;
    CHAR wave[4];
    CHAR fmt[4];
    UINT32 fmtLength;
    UINT16 fmtType;
    UINT16 channels;
    UINT32 sampleRate;
    UINT32 blockAlign;
    UINT16 byteRate;
    UINT16 bitsPerSample;
};

struct WaveDataHeader
{
    CHAR data[4];
    UINT32 dataSize;
};

struct AudioSource
{
    HRESULT LoadData(UINT32 bufferFrameCount, BYTE* pData, DWORD* flags, const WAVEFORMATEX& waveFormatOut)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        const UINT32 frameSize = waveFormatOut.wBitsPerSample / CHAR_BIT * waveFormatOut.nChannels;
        const UINT32 framesOut = dataOut.size() / frameSize;
        const UINT32 extraFrames = bufferFrameCount - framesOut;
        const UINT32 maxBytesToCopy = bufferFrameCount * frameSize;

        UINT32 bytesToCopy = dataOut.size();
        if (bytesToCopy > maxBytesToCopy)
        {
            bytesToCopy = maxBytesToCopy;
        }

        if (bytesToCopy == 0)
        {
            *flags = AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT;
        }

        memcpy(pData, dataOut.data(), bytesToCopy);
        memset(pData + bytesToCopy, 0, maxBytesToCopy - bytesToCopy);

        dataOut.erase(dataOut.begin(), dataOut.begin() + bytesToCopy);

        return hr;
    }

    HRESULT Read(const char* fileName, const WAVEFORMATEX& waveFormatOut)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
        if (file)
        {
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            const INT32 fileSize = ftell(file);
            rewind(file);

            WaveHeader waveFormatIn;
            fread(&waveFormatIn, sizeof(waveFormatIn), 1, file);

            WaveDataHeader dataHeader;
            do
            {
                fread(&dataHeader, sizeof(dataHeader), 1, file);

                if (dataHeader.data[0] == 'd' && dataHeader.data[1] == 'a' && dataHeader.data[2] == 't' && dataHeader.data[3] == 'a')
                {
                    break;
                }

                fseek(file, dataHeader.dataSize, SEEK_CUR);
            } while (ftell(file) != fileSize);

            BYTE* data = new BYTE[dataHeader.dataSize];
            fread(data, sizeof(data[0]), dataHeader.dataSize, file);

            dataIn.assign(data, data + dataHeader.dataSize);

            delete[] data;

            fclose(file);

            hr = Resample(waveFormatIn, waveFormatOut);
        }
        else
        {
            hr = S_FALSE;
        }

        return S_OK;
    }

private:
    HRESULT Resample(const WaveHeader& waveFormatIn, const WAVEFORMATEX& waveFormatOut)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        const INT32 bytesPerSampleIn = waveFormatIn.bitsPerSample / CHAR_BIT;
        const INT32 bytesPerSampleOut = waveFormatOut.wBitsPerSample / CHAR_BIT;
        const INT32 bytesPerFrameIn = bytesPerSampleIn * waveFormatIn.channels;
        const INT32 bytesPerFrameOut = bytesPerSampleOut * waveFormatOut.nChannels;

        const INT32 framesPerBytesIn = dataIn.size() / bytesPerFrameIn;
        const INT64 durationPerFramesIn = framesPerBytesIn * ReftimesPerSecond / waveFormatIn.sampleRate;
        const INT64 framesPerDurationOut = (durationPerFramesIn * waveFormatOut.nSamplesPerSec) / ReftimesPerSecond;
        const INT64 bytesPerFramesOut = bytesPerFrameOut * framesPerDurationOut;

        IMFTransform* resampler = nullptr;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CResamplerMediaObject, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMFTransform, (void**)&resampler);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        IMFMediaType* mediaTypeIn = nullptr;
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&mediaTypeIn);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        mediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
        mediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, waveFormatIn.channels);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK, SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, waveFormatIn.sampleRate);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, bytesPerFrameIn);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, waveFormatIn.sampleRate * bytesPerFrameIn);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, waveFormatIn.bitsPerSample);
        mediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

        IMFMediaType* mediaTypeOut = nullptr;
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&mediaTypeOut);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        mediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
        mediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_Float);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, waveFormatOut.nChannels);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK, SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, waveFormatOut.nSamplesPerSec);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, bytesPerFrameOut);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, waveFormatOut.nSamplesPerSec * bytesPerFrameOut);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, waveFormatOut.wBitsPerSample);
        mediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

        DWORD inputStreamID = 0;
        hr = resampler->SetInputType(inputStreamID, mediaTypeIn, 0);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = resampler->SetOutputType(0, mediaTypeOut, 0);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO streamInfo;
        hr = resampler->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &streamInfo);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        const bool resamplerNeedsSampleBuffer = (streamInfo.dwFlags & (MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES | MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES)) == 0;

        IMFSample* sampleIn = nullptr;
        hr = MFCreateSample(&sampleIn);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        IMFMediaBuffer* mediaBufferIn = nullptr;
        hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(dataIn.size(), &mediaBufferIn);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        BYTE* bufferIn = nullptr;
        DWORD maximumLength = 0;
        DWORD currentLength = 0;
        hr = mediaBufferIn->Lock(&bufferIn, &maximumLength, &currentLength);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        memcpy(bufferIn, dataIn.data(), dataIn.size());

        hr = mediaBufferIn->Unlock();
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = mediaBufferIn->SetCurrentLength(dataIn.size());
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = sampleIn->AddBuffer(mediaBufferIn);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = resampler->ProcessInput(inputStreamID, sampleIn, 0);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        IMFSample* sampleOut = nullptr;
        if (resamplerNeedsSampleBuffer)
        {
            hr = MFCreateSample(&sampleOut);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            IMFMediaBuffer* mediaBufferOut = nullptr;
            hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(bytesPerFramesOut, &mediaBufferOut);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            hr = sampleOut->AddBuffer(mediaBufferOut);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
        }

        MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputDataBuffer;
        outputDataBuffer.dwStreamID = 0;
        outputDataBuffer.pEvents = nullptr;
        outputDataBuffer.dwStatus = 0;
        outputDataBuffer.pSample = resamplerNeedsSampleBuffer ? sampleOut : nullptr;

        DWORD status = 0;
        hr = resampler->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputDataBuffer, &status);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        IMFMediaBuffer* outputBuffer = nullptr;
        hr = outputDataBuffer.pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&outputBuffer);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        BYTE* bufferOut = nullptr;
        DWORD currentLengthOut = 0;
        hr = outputBuffer->Lock(&bufferOut, nullptr, &currentLengthOut);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        dataOut.assign(bufferOut, bufferOut + currentLengthOut);

        return hr;
    }

    vector<BYTE> dataIn;
    vector<BYTE> dataOut;
};

HRESULT Run()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* deviceEnumerator = nullptr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&deviceEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    IMMDevice* device = nullptr;
    hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &device);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    IAudioClient* audioClient = nullptr;
    hr = device->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, nullptr, (void**)&audioClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    WAVEFORMATEX* waveFormat = nullptr;
    hr = audioClient->GetMixFormat(&waveFormat);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    const REFERENCE_TIME requestedDuration = ReftimesPerSecond;
    hr = audioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, requestedDuration, 0, waveFormat, nullptr);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    AudioSource audioSource;
    hr = audioSource.Read("../short1.wav", *waveFormat);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Get the actual size of the allocated buffer.
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount = 0;
    hr = audioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    IAudioRenderClient* renderClient = nullptr;
    hr = audioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioRenderClient), (void**)&renderClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Grab the entire buffer for the initial fill operation.
    BYTE* data = nullptr;
    hr = renderClient->GetBuffer(bufferFrameCount, &data);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Load the initial data into the shared buffer.
    DWORD flags = 0;
    hr = audioSource.LoadData(bufferFrameCount, data, &flags, *waveFormat);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = renderClient->ReleaseBuffer(bufferFrameCount, flags);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Start playing.
    hr = audioClient->Start();
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
    const REFERENCE_TIME actualDuration = ReftimesPerSecond * bufferFrameCount / waveFormat->nSamplesPerSec;
    const REFERENCE_TIME halfActualDurationInMilliseconds = actualDuration / ReftimesPerMillisecond / 2;

    // Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
    while (flags != AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT)
    {
        // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
        Sleep((DWORD)halfActualDurationInMilliseconds);

        // See how much buffer space is available.
        UINT32 paddingFrameCount = 0;
        hr = audioClient->GetCurrentPadding(&paddingFrameCount);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        const UINT32 availableFrameCount = bufferFrameCount - paddingFrameCount;

        // Grab all the available space in the shared buffer.
        hr = renderClient->GetBuffer(availableFrameCount, &data);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        // Get next 1/2-second of data from the audio source.
        hr = audioSource.LoadData(availableFrameCount, data, &flags, *waveFormat);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = renderClient->ReleaseBuffer(availableFrameCount, flags);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    }

    // Wait for last data in buffer to play before stopping.
    Sleep((DWORD)halfActualDurationInMilliseconds);

    // Stop playing.
    hr = audioClient->Stop();
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    Run();
}
```